# File not getting selected in the following Python Code

Tags: python-3.x

File not getting selected in the following Python Code. The message box should show the file name which is selected but this is showing none.

```
def ask_master_file_loc():
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    global contracts_v1
    contracts_v1 = glob.glob('file*.csv')
    messagebox.showinfo("Folder Selected", contracts_v1)
    upload.configure(bg = "#C0C0C0", state=DISABLED, relief = SUNKEN)
    create_folder.configure(bg = "#53e13d", state=NORMAL)
```

Comment: `contracts_v1 = glob.glob('file*.csv')`. Your problem is with this right?

Comment: I don't know where is the exact problem in this code, but i am not able to select the multiple csv file from this code

Comment: Most probably the working directory of the script is different from the one that has the csv files. Just add these lines above the `glob` line: `cwd = os.getcwd(); print(cwd)` and check if the current working directory has csv files or not.

Comment: This is a part of tool which i prepared....i am converting into .EXE then i am giving the tool to user to use it. So through  path = filedialog.askopenfilename() one dialog box opens and ask user about the location of file. It has no relation with cwd = os.getcwd(); print(cwd).

Comment: Try writing `glob.glob(path + '/file*.csv')` then.